# .Net Maui a picker with multiple selection? or CollectionView with dropdown multi select option?

Tags: maui

I understand there is no out-of-the-box feature for a multi-select picker.
I tried COllectionView with selectionMode as Multiple but it gives the list of values and my ItemSource value can grow up to 50 items and I don not want to display each item. Instead, I would need a single column with a list of values that can be picked just like a Picker.
What I need is a single column with multiple selection options.

There are some suggestions for installing the **Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility** package from NuGet but it is only available for 8.0 version and my project is 7.0

Here is the same CollectionView for reference.

```
                        <CollectionView x:Name="TestCollectionView"  SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding MultiselectionDependedTasks}" SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems , Source={x:Reference TestCollectionView}}"  ItemsSource="{Binding DependentTasks}" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedDependentTasks}" >
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate >
                                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CollectionView>
```

Please suggest if any other solution I can look for

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “checkbox option”?  Which platform are you testing on?

Comment: I am testing on .net maui Windows app.  I updated my question with CollectionView is using to display multiselect. It displays the list view. What I would need is the single column with list of selection values

Comment: AFAIK Android/iOS don't have a checkbox - see the screenshot in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection#multiple-preselection)

Comment: Thanks Jason. I am looking for singly Column with list of values to be picked (Multiple values to be picked) . Picker in .net Maui is only single value selectable

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the multiple selection mode of `CollectionView` to achieve this.

When the `SelectionMode` property is set to `Multiple`, multiple items in the CollectionView can be selected. When items are selected, the `SelectedItems` property is set to the selected items. When this property changes, the `SelectionChangedCommand` is executed (with the value of the `SelectionChangedCommandParameter` being passed to the `ICommand`, and the `SelectionChanged` event fires.

The following XAML example shows a CollectionView that can respond to multiple item selection:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                SelectionMode="Multiple"
                SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged">
    ...
</CollectionView>
```

For more information, please check document : [Multiple selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection#multiple-selection).

**Note:**

You can also make a custom `MultiSelectionPicker`.

The idea us to create a new custom control inherited with Entry control, which will focus on the picker. The Multi-Item Selection Picker listing is nothing but a content page with list view control that has the check box template. Also, we also need to use await able content page which will return the data when the page closes.

For more information, please check: [Multiple Item Selection Picker](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/multiple-item-selection-picker-in-xamarin-forms/). Although it is based on xamarin-form, it also applies to Maui.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. I added the CollectionView inside the expander like below. It expands when you click and shows the CollectionView only when the user clicks on it.

```
                            <toolkit:Expander>
                                <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="42" Padding="10"  >
                                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding AddedPrecursor}" />
                                        <Label Text="&#9660;" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </toolkit:Expander.Header>

                                <toolkit:Expander.Content>

                                    <CollectionView x:Name="TestCollectionView" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding MultiselectionDependedTasks}" SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems , Source={x:Reference TestCollectionView}}"  ItemsSource="{Binding DependentTasks}" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedDependentTasks}" WidthRequest="200" >
                                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate >
                                                <Label Text="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="LightGray" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </CollectionView>
                                </toolkit:Expander.Content>
                            </toolkit:Expander>
```